# Need ability to determine the Level of the log as passes from main function

Tags: python, logging, format

Need ability to determine the Level of the log as passes from main function e.g.
**log_it_all(log_path).info(log_msg), log_it_all(log_path).error(log_msg**).
based on those levels the details in a format will change

````
import logging
import os


def log_it_all(log_path_name):
    '''NEED: ability to determine the Level of the log as passes from main function e.g. 

        log_it_all(log_path).info(log_msg)
        log_it_all(log_path).error(log_msg)

        based on those level the details in a format will change
    '''
    log_format = ''
    if('Error' or 'Critical'):
        log_format = '[Line# %(lineno)d in %(filename)s | %(pathname)s]' + ' ' + \
            '%(name)s %(funcName)s |%(thread)d %(threadName)s |%(process)d %(processName)s'
    if('Worning'):
        log_format = '[Line# %(lineno)d in %(filename)s | %(pathname)s]'

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s ' +
                        ' ' + log_format,
                        handlers=[logging.FileHandler(log_path_name, mode='a'),
                                  logging.StreamHandler()])
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)


log_msg = 'MyTest'
log_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '_MyLog.log')
log_it_all(log_path).info(log_msg)
log_it_all(log_path).error(log_msg)```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the logger from your function, you could just pass the message to the function and log it in the function:

```
def log_it_all(log_path_name, log_level, log_msg):
    log_format = ''
    if log_level.isin([logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL]):
         log_format = '[Line# %(lineno)d in %(filename)s | %(pathname)s]' + ' ' + \
        '%(name)s %(funcName)s |%(thread)d %(threadName)s |%(process)d %(processName)s'
    elif log_level == logging.WARNING:
         log_format = '[Line# %(lineno)d in %(filename)s | %(pathname)s]'
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s ' +
                    ' ' + log_format,
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler(log_path_name, mode='a'),
                              logging.StreamHandler()])
    logging.getLogger(__name__).log(log_level, log_msg)

log_msg = 'MyTest'
log_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '_MyLog.log')
log_it_all(log_path, logging.INFO, log_msg)
log_it_all(log_path, logging.ERROR, log_msg)
```

Comment: The log_level is an Integer, so I made a modification
    if log_level > 30:
    # if log_level.isin([logging.ERROR, logging.CRITICAL]):